# liquibase with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, liquibase

I am new to both technologies and My application is up in a remote server and we are deploying the application through Jenkins. Now we want to track all DB changes and are planning to use Liquibase. How can I integrate Liquibase with Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Job that is executed in a Windows batch file as following:

```
SET LIQUIBASE_HOME="C:\liquibase-3.8.2\"
SET logfile="procedures.log"
SET driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
SET classpath="../sqljdbc_8.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre8.jar"
SET url="jdbc:sqlserver://"
SET dbhost=192.168.0.1
SET dbport=1433
SET databasename="Ku"
SET dbusername="upgrade"
SET dbpassword="upgrade"
SET changeLogFile="procedures.xml"
SET loglevel="ERROR"
cd "%LIQUIBASE_HOME%"
liquibase --driver=%driver% --classpath=%classpath%  --changeLogFile=%AuditChangeSet% --url=%url%%dbHostPort%;databaseName=%databasename%  ^
--username=%dbusername% --password=%dbpassword% --logLevel=%loglevel% update
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a jenkins plugin available for liquibase

https://plugins.jenkins.io/liquibase-runner/

you can also consider writing shell scripts that does the job for you.